# IE - "Error: Object doesn't support this action"

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a frustrating javascript error in IE7 that I can't get around.  It is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE..

The line I am getting the error in is: `item = listGetAt(list,'1','-');`

This is calling the following custom method:

```
function listGetAt(list,position,delimiter) {   
if(delimiter == null) { delimiter = '-'; }
list = list.split(delimiter);
if(list.length > position) {
    return list[position];
} else {
    return list.length;
}
}
```

Can anyone see something I can't?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Jason

Comment: what exactly does `list` contain? It is poor naming convention to call it list all the time - at some stage it will be an array

Comment: found the problem.. it looks like "item" is a reserved word.. when I changed the the var name to 'selectedItem', it worked fine..

Comment: still poor code, and don't pass '1' to the function instead pass 1

Comment: @Jason `item` is not a reserved word

Comment: Thanks Alvin.. must have been conflicting with some other code then.. strange only had the conflict though.. cheers

Comment: Item may very well be reserved in IE since collections have collection.item() and everything in IE is also in a collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poor code

Why pass a string as a numeric parameter?

I would consider

```
function listGetAt(list,position,delimiter) {   
  delimiter = delimiter || '-';
  if (list.indexOf(delimiter) ==-1) return -1;
  list = list.split(delimiter);
  return list.length>=position?list[position]:null;
}
```

Comment: thanks mplunjan.. it was an int originally.. just left it there while playing around trying to work out what IEs problem was and must have forgotten to remove it..that being said, this method was not the problem.. it was the variable receiving the call to it.  Thanks for your suggestions.